# Import Only some Cert.'s in a P7b

Tags: powershell, security, certificate, p7b

I have a certificates.p7b file with 2 certificates in it. Lets Call the Certs A and B.

if I run

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath $CertFile -CertStoreLocation $CertStoreMY
```

It will import both certificate A and B. I only want to import certificate A

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to import the file with both certificates.
Then export each certificate separately creating a separate file for each certificate.